Help identifying wall cap/plug underneath faux fireplace
Background
I have an old home from the 1920's. It has a faux fireplace w/ no attached chimney. It appears to be originally added when house was built.
There's a 4" galvanized metal cap on the wall below the mantle. The cap has no screws to remove it. I'm guessing it's similar to this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-Round-Duct-Cap-DC4/100396932
More pictures and video at https://imgur.com/a/unknown-wall-cap-plug-underneath-faux-fireplace-z26erOS. This includes a video I took from a camera scope that gives a view behind the cap/plug.
Questions

What this cap/plug is for, i.e. why was it added? I took a camera scope to look behind the cap and there's no duct work from what I can tell so unclear what the purpose of it is.
How best to remove it? My goal is to put fish some low-voltage cabling through it. It seems firmly attached but not sure if that's just the paint.



Is this an outside wall? If so, perhaps there originally was a wood stove or similar item in this location venting straight out the back and they capped the hole.

Yes, it is an outside wall. A wood stove would make sense. I didn’t see any artifacts of that on the scope camera but maybe the angle wasn’t right. Thanks!
